# SQL Database size doesn't match with the total table sizes in the database

Tags: sql-server-2005, size

I have a database that is size about 104GB.

When I calculate the total table sizes in the database it's only about 24GB. This includes Data+index+unused spaces.

Why the DB size is too large?

Comment: Do you have LOB storage? XML columns? I am assuming this is SQL Server...?

Comment: Have you tried compacting the database? Are you taking into account padding, metadata and other fancy stuff internal to the storage engine?

Comment: Are you talking about the total size of your database?, I mean, data (.mdf file) and log (.ldf file)?

Comment: (Assuming MS SQL Server) The database size includes the transaction log (.ldf file(s)).  You need to look at specific file sizes.

Comment: How do you calculate unused spaces? Databases usually trade space for speed, and allocate huge amounts of disk space ahead of time, to avoid allocation at transaction time. Space freed by `delete` may be reused or not due to speed reasons; try coalescing some of the database objects to reclaim it.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't reclaim space from the physical disk (for performance reasons), so your file on disk might be significantly bigger than the actual objects contained in it. SQL Server will reuse that "empty" space when needed, so that you might be able to stuff 80 GB of new data into your database without seeing any increase in the file size

Comment: @Yuck - Its is SQL server 2005. There is no XML Columns. Not sure about LOB storage. @

Comment: @ Lamak - yes I consider both files

Comment: @ squillman - I did consider both

Comment: @9000, sp_spaceused, Also I see my mdf and ldf files

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the RDBMS being used, it is possible that the large file size as compared to summed-up table sizes is caused by any or more than one of the following:

- Last database cleanup (in terms of table deletion, record deletion, etc) did not affect any disk reclamation by the OS/RDBMS
- Last database cleanup does not normally affect disk space reclamation by OS/RDBMS
- Indexes/constraints are being stored in other files. You won't see these when checking just table sizes.
- No shrinking has been performed, though that may also possibly end up as first and/or second in this list
- A possible miscalculation of table size retrieval (I just need to add this because it happens to some) and so the numbers don't tally
- And maybe a few others.. Hopefully the stackers can add

I'm not saying these are definite items that impact your situation. I just mean that these may occur, and not just in your situation..

- One other thing. It can also depend on the database settings for new disk allocation sizes. Say for example one allocation for a certain DB is 1GB. Once the usage exceeds that, another 1GB is added, regardless of whether or not you consumed all of it -- at the moment more allocation is required, it gets set.

Comment: Thank you. One other think I am noticing is that, my db's initial size is 101890MB. I am not how did it happen?

Comment: Is this a production database? Do you have enough resources to back this up and restore it as a copy/non-production db? Then you can try to check the allocation size; I'm trying to remember if you can alter this by SQL.. Then you can also try to shrink the database. You can check your DB settings and search for an applicable `shrink` command: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907511 --- *AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE* perform these tests on a non-production copy of the database. Try to restore your most recent backup, or even back the DB up right now, restore elsewhere, then use that instance to test..

Comment: This is in production server. I don't have enough space to backup the db

Answer (score 3):

In one of your comments you said the initial size of the database is shown in SSMS as 101890MB. That's why the database is so large, it was created at that size.

As to how/why it was created at 104GB, check the model database on that server. Good odds someone has fiddled with the defaults in model and your database has inherited those when you created it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about os file size versus computed bytes for the records you store, then this will depend on your database type. If you take Oracle as an example, you create tablespaces as containers for your tables and indexes. These tablespaces pre-allocate space on disk via data files. Then you start allocating blocks out of the tablespace for different tables until your tablespace is full. But you may not have even created a table yet but the os will have a file for the empty tablespace.  Then you also have tablespaces for system tables, rollback information, journaling information and the like. So there is a certain amount of overhead before you even get into record counts.

If you did a dump of your data tables, the files generated by the dump may be more closely related to your calculated data sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am on SQL server 2005 OS-2003